# Determining if a point lies on the interior of a polygon

Tags: javascript, algorithm, polygon

my english is bad can someone who understand the subject correct me
Is the point inside or outside?
my goal is to detect if multiple points are inside or outside the polygon and determine what's outside

The following is a simple solution to the problem often encountered in computer graphics, determining whether or not a point (x,y) lies inside or outside a 2D polygonally bounded plane. This is necessary for example in applications such as polygon filling on raster devices. hatching in drafting software, and determining the intersection of multiple polygons.

[image]

```js
var canvas = window.document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var W = 500;
var H = 600;

    var a = 0;
    var b = 0;

var point_array = [[0,0]];

if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("select_point")) != null){

    for(var i = point_array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        point_array.splice(i, 1);
    }

    point_array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("select_point"));
}

var point = [W/2, H/2];

canvas.onclick = function(evt){
    point[0] = evt.pageX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    point[1] = evt.pageY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    if(localStorage.getItem("select_point") == null){
        if(point_array[0][0] == 0 && point_array[0][1] == 0){
            point_array.splice(0, 1);
        }
        point_array.push([point[0],point[1]]);
    }
    test();
};

test();

function sifirla(){
    localStorage.removeItem("select_point");
    window.location.reload();
}

function aktar(){
    localStorage.setItem("select_point", JSON.stringify(point_array));
    window.location.reload();
}

function sign(p, p2, p3){
    return (p[0] - p3[0]) * (p2[1] - p3[1]) - (p2[0] - p3[0]) * (p[1] - p3[1]);
}

function PointInTriangle(pt, polygon){
    
    var d = [];
    var has_neg, has_pos;

    a = 0;
    b = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < polygon.length-1; i++){
        var ss = sign(pt, polygon[i], polygon[i+1]);
        d.push(ss);

        if(ss > 0){ a++; }
        if(ss < 0){ b++; }
        
    }
    /*d1 = this.sign(pt, v1, v2);
    d2 = this.sign(pt, v2, v3);
    d3 = this.sign(pt, v3, v1);

    has_neg = (d1 < 0) || (d2 < 0) || (d3 < 0);
    has_pos = (d1 > 0) || (d2 > 0) || (d3 > 0);

    return !(has_neg && has_pos);*/
    return true;
}

function zero_death(num){
    if(num < 0){ num = num*-1; }
    return num;
}

function test(){
    var result = PointInTriangle(point, point_array);

    var info = "point = [" + point[0] + "," + point[1] + "]\n";
    info += "+: "+a+"-: "+b+"\n";
    for(var i = 0; i < point_array.length; i++){
        info += "point_array\t["+i+"][" + point_array[i][0] + "," + point_array[i][1] + "] \t ["+zero_death(point_array[i][0]-point[0])+","+zero_death(point_array[i][1]-point[1])+"]("+(zero_death(point_array[i][0]-point[0])+zero_death(point_array[i][1]-point[1]))+")\n";
    }
    info += "result = " + (result ? "true" : "false");

    window.document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = info;
    render();
}

function render(){
    ctx.fillStyle = "#CCCCCC";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 600);
    drawTriangle(point_array);
    drawPoint(point);
    //appendTriangle(point_array);
    pastePoint(point_array);
}

function pastePoint(polygon){

    var result = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < point_array.length; i++){
        result.push([i,((zero_death(point_array[i][0]-point[0])+zero_death(point_array[i][1]-point[1])))]);
    }
    result.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a[1] - b[1];
    });

    ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(point[0], point[1]);

            ctx.lineTo(point[0], point[1]);
            ctx.lineTo(polygon[result[0][0]][0], polygon[result[0][0]][1]);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
    
        ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(point[0], point[1]);

            ctx.lineTo(point[0], point[1]);
            ctx.lineTo(polygon[result[1][0]][0], polygon[result[1][0]][1]);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
    
}

function appendTriangle(polygon){

    ctx.beginPath();
        for(var i = 0; i < (polygon.length/3)-1; i++){
            ctx.moveTo(polygon[(i*3)+0][0], polygon[(i*3)+0][1]);

            ctx.lineTo(polygon[(i*3)+0][0], polygon[(i*3)+0][1]);
            ctx.lineTo(polygon[(i*3)+1][0], polygon[(i*3)+1][1]);
            ctx.lineTo(polygon[(i*3)+2][0], polygon[(i*3)+2][1]);
        }
    ctx.stroke();
    
}

function drawTriangle(polygon){
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(polygon[0][0], polygon[0][1]);
    for(var i = 0; i < polygon.length; i++){
        ctx.lineTo(polygon[i][0], polygon[i][1]);
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.font = "12px monospace";
    for(var i = 0; i < polygon.length; i++){
        ctx.fillText(i, polygon[i][0], polygon[i][1]);
    }
}

function drawPoint(p){
    ctx.fillStyle = "#F00";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(p[0], p[1], 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
}
```

```css
canvas{
    background: #f1f1f1;
    border:1px solid #eeeeee;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="500" height="600" style="float:left;margin-right:15px;"></canvas>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Here's the algorithm I use: 1) pick a point that is definitely outside 2) connect it to the point you want to test 3) count how often the resulting line intersects a side of the polygon => even result: point is also outside; odd result: point is inside

Comment: @Ramazan the algorithm outlined by Chris is called "Ray casting algorithm": chances are if you Google that, you'll find one implemented in JS.

Comment: Note that there's an edge case where the line crosses the polygon exactly at one of its vertices; to prevent a wrong result you need to test the connecting line against the edge line & its starting point but not its ending point (also, this question is dupe)

Comment: What is the question ??